# pre-requisite C programming knowledge for ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i am new to ROS. i want to know that if advance programming concpts in C programming(e.g inheritance etc) are essential to understand ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36986/pre-requisite-c-programming-knowledge-for-ros?/) by [hina](https://answers.ros.org/users/2679/hina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't want to sound too critical, but ROS uses C++, not C. The ROS API is strictly object-oriented in nature, so it's essential that you at least understand how to instantiate/use objects.

Here's my list of programming concepts that you should understand if you were to use C++ in ROS:

**Object-Oriented Design**: If you're going to code using ROSCpp, it's vital that you at least understand how to instantiate, handle, destroy, and pass objects. This applies to using Python with ROS as well.

**Interface Programming**: Any time that you use ROS's pluginlib features, you will be required to utilize interfaces to create your plugins. In terms of C++, this means inheriting from a base class and implementing virtual functions. So if you want to use [pluginlib](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pluginlib), you will need to understand inheritance. Inheritance also exists in Python, so it's a good concept to know either way.

**Real-time Programming**: Based on your application, you might need to understand the concepts of real-time programming to achieve your goals.

**Boost**: Boost is an incredibly powerful and helpful library, and ROS already includes it as a dependency, so you should learn how to use if you're going to use ROSCpp.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically you can also use Python as your programming language which i would recommend if you don't have any advanced programming skills in C++, Java or LISP.

Nevertheless, programming concepts like inheritance are important and i would strongly recommend to have a look at them regardless of which programming language you want to use...

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7